# how to plot the figure as improfile shows

Tags: matlab

When I draw a line segment on my figure I can get the 2-D plot by `improfile();`
[image]

But now, I need to draw 1000 pictures so I can not do it manually,

I tried to get the return of improfile and save into `M`
Then plot it , but it didn't work.
The output was empty
[image]

```
im=imread('./sample.jpeg');
% im=imread('./red.jpeg');
imshow(im,[]);
x=[50,50];
y=[80,80];
% improfile();
M = improfile(im,x,y);
plot3(M(:,1), M(:,2), M(:,3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is your `x` and `y` variables, they should hold the the coordinates of each point on you're line. However, you're specifying the same coordinate twice so it's not a line but a point which explains why `M` is only a 1x1x3 variable.

You're variable `M` holds a row vector for each of the colors if you're using RGB images. To get an exact plot like `improfile` does you therefore need to plot three lines instead of a single 3D line. Furthermore this requires the location on the line of each interpolated value, which you can probably get from `improfile` as well, just look at the source and help of the function for that.

```
im = imread( './sample.jpeg' );
imshow( im, [] );
x = [ 50, 80 ];
y = [ 50, 80 ];
[ M ] = improfile( im, x, y );

D = 1 : length( M );
plot( ...
    D, M( :, :, 1 ), 'r' ...
  , D, M( :, :, 2 ), 'g' ...
  , D, M( :, :, 3 ), 'b' ...
);
```

Comment: if I want to check if the plot output is identical to the manual test, how could I draw the line segment from the point (50,50) -> (80, 80) via the UI window, thanks

Comment: Only plotting that part of the image, so `imshow( im( 50:80, 50:80 ), [] );` and select the top-left and bottom-right corner might do that trick.